# Is there any way to auto submit gravity form according to radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I am setting up a new gravity form, where i need to get auto form submission trigger when someone click on radio button "No".

here is my form - https://wpskillguru.com/test/

I added below code in theme's "function.php" file

```
 add_filter( 'gchoice_22_1_1', 'add_onclick', 10, 2 );
function add_onclick( $button, $form, $radio ) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('form#gform_22_1_1').trigger('gform_submit_button_22');

});
```

but don't know how to set "onclick event" in Radio button

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.on()** method and attach the event handler with it. You can read more about it [here](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(".ginput_container_radio").on("click", "input[value='No']", function(){
     alert("No select!");
     // your code here
});
```

or

```
$(".ginput_container_radio").on("change", "input[value='No']", function(){
         alert("No select!");
         // your code here
});
```

Note: The *ginput_container_radio* is taken from the radio buttons at https://wpskillguru.com/test

Comment: thanks for your reply, could you tell me where should i paste above code in my theme?here is my gravity form' fields screenshot - http://prntscr.com/p1353j

Comment: Can you please send me a "final code" after add my code, and also send me a onclick code to insert in "gravity radio button" field

Answer (score 0):

To submit the form after clicking a Gravity Forms Radio Button you can use the following code:

```js
$( '.ginput_container_radio input' ).on( 'change', function() {
    $( '#gform_GFFORMID' ).submit();
} );
```

The best way to install this code is the free [Gravity Forms Custom JavaScript](https://gravitywiz.com/gravity-forms-custom-javascript/) plugin.

If you're looking for a way to auto-submit a form without any code, check out our [GF Page Transitions](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-page-transitions/) add-on.